# Rails association has_many and has_many through on same STI model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations, sti

I have a model Note. 
Notes are very useful and are used for lots of purposes throughout the application.

We have another model User, and these are STI split between 
User1s
and 
User2s

We have a third model Thing, which are things belonging to Users... I'll leave it there for the moment as it gets a touch more complicated, (there are other models a bit like Things which one can likewise make notes on).

```
Note.rb
belongs_to :user #This signifies that the user wrote the note
belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: :true #This is what the note is referring to

User.rb
has_many :user_notes, class_name: "Note", foreign_key: "user_id" 
#signifies the note was written by the User

User1.rb < User
has_many :notes, as: :notable 
#Signifies the note was about the User1
has_many :things

User2.rb < User
has_many :notes, as: :notable 
#Signifies the note was about the User2


Thing.rb
belongs_to :user1
has_many :notes, as: :notable 
#The note is about the thing
```

These can be, but are not generally, self-referential (I write a note about myself).

Often User1s will write notes about User2s, or about User2s Things so that User2 can see them.

I think I've taken the correct route in renaming the user_notes.

I'm struggling with how one collects together all the notes that might be related to me. 
i.e. Let's say I'm a user1. 
I'd like to see the notes I've written, plus notes other people have written about me, plus the notes that have been written about my things.

Is there an easy way to do that? 
I'm struggling with two points.

1. How can I connect the notes about my things?

   has_many :thing_notes, through: :things, source: :notes

works, but I wonder if it's the correct way of approaching it.

Also, I'm interested in the reverse (which is also sort of useful), in this case ignoring who might have written the note, to return the relevant user1, if there is one. But...

```
delegate :user1, to: :notable
```

doesn't make sense if user1 is already a potential notable_type.

2. How can I collate all my notes (of whatever type) and return them?

i.e.

```
@user1.notes
```

will return just the notes about me

```
@user1.user_notes
```

will return notes I've written

```
@user1.thing_notes
```

will return notes about my things

I could merge them together, but I'll risk there being annoying duplicates, and it seems a shame to make multiple database calls and lose db ordering when they're all of one type...

Is there an obvious way to get all my notes...?

```
Note.where("(user_id = :user1_id) OR (notable_id = :user1_id AND notable_type = 'User') OR (notable_type = 'Thing' AND notable_id IN (:things))", user1_id: user1.id, things:user1.thing_ids)
```

is a touch on the ugly side and will only get uglier...

Hope that makes sense to someone who loves to solve such puzzles...

Comment: Is there a reason not to have `Thing` with `belongs_to :user` instead of `user1`?

Comment: From a system logic point of view, yes. User2s don't have things. (Though they do have thing2s and thing3s, for the sake of argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the collation, if you're using Rails 5, you could do something like this to simplify the raw SQL:

```
Note.where(user: user1).or(Note.where(notable: user1)).or(Note.where(notable: user1.things))
```

If you're not using Rails 5, you can include this gem for the same functionality: https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or

Comment: Not looking to upgrade to Rails 5 just yet. Need to avoid that pain where possible. I'll check out that gem. Certainly makes the query a little cleaner. 
the question is then how would you suggest using that query. 
Is there a way to sensibly integrate that with activerecord or scopes? Or just have it as an instance method on User1? Or perhaps a class method/scope on notes and then recursively call it.  
I was thinking of putting scopes such that I could have .all_notes or .notes_about_me (would exclude notes I'd written that weren't about me).

Comment: If you want to access them separately at some point, then the scopes make sense. They can be used as instance methods.